# Is static initialization guaranteed here?

Tags: c++

Look at this code:

```
struct Foo {
        void *ptr;

        constexpr Foo() : ptr(nullptr) { }
};

Foo f;
```

Is it guaranteed that `f` will be statically initialized?

Clang uses static initialization here, but MSVC [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/g/SS4y8x).

Comment: I would think that Clang does an optimization since it detect that the constructor zero-initialize the memory. I would not think that such optimization is required as it would only works in trivial cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Standard says `f` will be constant initialized:

[basic.start.init]/2:

> A *constant initializer* for an object `o` is an expression that is a constant expression, except that it may also invoke `constexpr` constructors for `o` and its subobjects even if those objects are of non-literal class types [*Note:* such a class may have a non-trivial destructor --*end note*]. *Constant initialization* is performed:
>
> - ... [a case for references]
> - if an object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constructor call, and if the initialization full-expression is a constant initializer for the object;
> - ... [a case for objects initialized without a constructor call]
>
> Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called *static initialization*; all other initialization is *dynamic initialization*. Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.

The initialization full-expression is simply the call of `Foo`'s default constructor, which is a constant expression.

MSVC is wrong to emit code to initialize `f`.

Answer (score 0):

Standard-wise, yes. Reality-wise, no.

You are at the mercy of compiler venders when it comes to static initialization compliance.

[edit] Clang is a special compiler — from the beginning its creators have been interested in full standards compliance.

Comment: That article appears to be misusing the term "static initialization" to talk about "dynamic initialization".  The Static Initialization Order Fiasco (also a confusing name) only happens when both initializers use dynamic initialization.

Comment: Hmm... you are right. /my brain dead. I'll remove it from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be also in msvc (at least vs 2015) if you were to declare the f itself as constexpr Foo f;

Comment: Except that unnecessarily stops you from ever modifying `f` during the program.

Comment: Sure. Depending on your goals it can be ok or not.